# AS3 Boolean seemingly not working

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok, so this is obviously going to be something that I stupidly overlooked in my code, but I am having problems with a boolean check in as3. In the below if statement I set a boolean, I can confirm that the boolean is set in this if switch as I have run a trace to check that:

```
if(switchA && switchB){
                if(Side == "LEFT"){
                    localAttachCoords.x = (-Parent.collision.SideLength - entity.collision.SideLength)/2
                    localAttachCoords.y = Parent.collision.SideLength/2 - (((TargNode-1)*8) + entity.collision.SideLength/2)
                }
                if(Side == "RIGHT"){
                    localAttachCoords.x = (Parent.collision.SideLength + entity.collision.SideLength)/2
                    localAttachCoords.y = -(Parent.collision.SideLength/2 - (((TargNode-1)*8) + entity.collision.SideLength/2))
                }
                if(Side == "UP"){
                    localAttachCoords.y = (Parent.collision.SideLength + entity.collision.SideLength)/2
                    localAttachCoords.x = -(Parent.collision.SideLength/2 - (((TargNode-1)*8) + entity.collision.SideLength/2))
                }
                if(Side == "DOWN"){
                    localAttachCoords.y = (-Parent.collision.SideLength - entity.collision.SideLength)/2
                    localAttachCoords.x = Parent.collision.SideLength/2 - (((TargNode-1)*8) + entity.collision.SideLength/2)
                }
                entity.attached = true
                entity.Parent = Parent
            }
```

This would all be well and good, but for the fact that in a function from another class, executed every frame, claims that the boolean was set to false, I confirmed this with another trace function.
This is the function, taken from the class whose instance is referred to as `entity` in the above switch:

```
  public function update(){
        if (physics) physics.update()
        if (node && physics){
            trace(attached)
            if(attached){
                physics.nodeUpdate()
            }
        }
    }
```

This function claims in the trace that attached == false despite it being set true earlier with no other reference to the attached variable. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you're shadowing your global variable with a local one ?

Comment: You may use set and get function for attached, and check when the attached value is changed in the set function .

Comment: @Loremlpsum: The variable is the only one of its name in my entire project, thanks for taking the time to try answering this though

Answer (score 0):

### Pathing

There are some un-addressed variables in your issue, foremost being the pathing you're taking to check your variable.  This is relevant because of namespaces/scope affect what each piece of code has access to.

If your functions and variables shared the same space (i.e., global/document/timeline), then any reference the the same named variable will always return the same value, unless (as [LoremIpsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989109/as3-boolean-seemingly-not-working#comment-26301789) noted) it's being shadowed by a local variable by the same name.

Obviously, this is not the case since you're using `public function` which is a class-only declaration.  If the boolean you're looking for is on the timeline, and the class wants to read that variable, you need to have a valid path to it.  Instantiated classes that are DisplayObjects and have been added to the DisplayList have both `parent` and `stage` properties which you can use to access the timeline global namespace (thereby providing access to your boolean).

However, if the class is not a DisplayObject (e.g., it does not `extend` a `Sprite`, `Shape`, or `MovieClip`), then access to the timeline has to be provided manually, either by setting a property on the class, or passing an argument to a method on the class.

Further complicating the matter is if the Boolean exists in another class object (either instantiated or static), you'd then need a way to get between them.  A case of A sees B, C sees B, but neither A or C see eachother.

---

### Values

A boolean is always going to be false, even if the assigned value was `null`, so if your class is trying to reference a variable that it can't see, that value will always be false.  For example...

```
var foo:Boolean = this["fiddlesticks"];
trace("foo = " + foo); // traces: "foo = false"
```

There is no property `this.fiddlesticks`, so while the resolved value is null, foo becomes false.  Consider using [`hasOwnProperty()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29), which indicates whether an object has a specified property defined, and is a method available to all objects.

---

### Switch

You don't have to manually create your own switch using `if then else if`, AS3 has its own [`switch`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#switch) statement.

```
switch (Side) {
    case "LEFT":
        // Do stuff for left
        break;
    case "RIGHT":
        // Do stuff for right
        break;
    case "UP":
        // Throw your hands up
        break;
    case "DOWN":
        // Get down and boogie!
        break;
}
```

I hope that all helps.  I'd like to say exactly what's going on with the access to your Boolean, but there simply isn't enough information to say.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank's for the info, especially with the switch part, save some time :) Unfortunately, the pathing and values sections are of little help to me, I have thuroughly looked at them, going through call stacks and using trace commands. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Can you expound on your setup?  How are your classes setup and where are these variables accesses coming from?

Comment: ok, the first snippet of code is from a class called `Node()` which is a component of the `Entity` class, where the second snippet is taken from. the variable `attached` is a public variable defined in the `Entity` class, who's instance is given to the `Node` class inside the files that extend `Entity`. I can put up some of the source later, but I do not have access to my code at this time.